# a prime number behind a picture

Tags: wordplay, rebus, knowledge

Over the time people collect tons of characters in movies, songs and games.

I'm sure you don't need to know all of them neither for the resulting **prime number**.

[image: the description is really unimportant]

Here are my first 2 hints. Yes, two, because the first is already part of my comment.

Hint 1:

> Halle berry

Hint 2:

> Hannibal

Comment: The head(+1 Onix body) counts upto 21. so is the prime near 21?

Comment: Well. I don't want to give a hint yet. But 21 is totally wrong.

Comment: I was not aware that 21 is a PRIME...:)

Comment: @Moti To be fair, he did say *near* 21

Comment: So 19 and 23 are not...:)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a lot of these characters, but it seams to me that their names start with different letter. [U]sain Bolt, [N]ed Flanders, [H]ugo Weaving, [R]emy (from Ratatouille), [E]lvis Presley, Does someone see 2 characters starting with the same letter so I can stop going this path?

Comment: @Marius Hannibal and Halle Berry, Ernie and Elvis.

Comment: [H]alle Berry. Or maybe I should really write [H]alle berry.

Comment: @Sleafar Instead of Hanibal it can be Antony Hopkins and it could still fit my patterns, but you are right. Enrie and Elvis...Thanks. Back to square 1.

Comment: @Marius It's the other [Hannibal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_A-Team) (George Peppard).

Comment: @Sleafar.Oups :). Ignore me for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> 397

The pictures spell out a clue

> **F**arin Urlaub 
> **O**nix 
> **U**mberto Eco 
> **R**emy 
> **H**alle Berry 
> **U**rgot 
> **N**ilsson 
> **D**onkey Kong 
> **R**udolph 
> **E**lrond 
> **D**arth Vader 
> **M**acguyver 
> **I**ndiana Jones 
> **N**ed Flanders 
> **U**sain Bolt 
> **S**cotty 
> **T**iger Woods 
> **H**annibal Smith 
> **R**exxar 
> **E**lvis Presley 
> **E**rnie

Also

> 397 is a cuban prime which may explain the background

Comment: Amazing!!! One question: Did you use tineye.com or something else to get faces from the image?

Comment: Switch Ned Flanders and Farin Urlaub.

Comment: I knew all but four of them and used google reverse image search to get the others. Didn't recognise Farin Urlaub though. Thanks @Sleafar